# RTCPeerconnection.onicecandidate not firing

Tags: next.js, webrtc

I have defined my a `useEffect` in my NextJS component as follows:

```
useEffect(() => {
    // setting up a peer connection
    const peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(servers);
    getLocalMedia();

    // getting the ice candidates from the stun server
    peerConnection.onicecandidate = (event) => {
        if (event.candidate != null) {
            console.log("this is an iceCandidate", event.candidate);
        } else {
            console.log("No more ice candidates");
        }
    }

    // creating an offer
    const createOffer = async () => {
        const offer = await peerConnection.createOffer();
        const offerObject = {
            sdp: offer.sdp,
            type: offer.type
        }

        console.log(offerObject);
        await peerConnection.setLocalDescription(offer);
    }

    createOffer();
})
```

I am able to `console.log()` the offer object, but I am not getting any ice candidate in the console. What have I possibly done wrong?

I tried going through the docs of MDN, it had the same syntax.